# Whats wrong with my php code?

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone tell me whats wrong in this code?

```
protected function update() {
            if(@$_POST['lat'] == "" && @$_POST['lng'] == "" && @$_POST['bool'] == "")
                    return array("message"=>"lat, lng is missing");
                       $lat = $_POST['lat'];
                    $lng = $_POST['lng'];
                    $bool = $_POST['bool'];                       

                $sql = "UPDATE markers SET bool='$bool' WHERE lat=? AND lng=?";

             $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

                    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$lat,$lng,$bool);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                    $mysqli->close();

 }
```

i get this error:

```
  mysqli_stmt::bind_param():
 Number of variables doesn't match number in prepared statement?
        in line 96.($stmt->bind_param("sss",$lat,$lng,$bool);
```

But i don't know why? because it looks like the statement should be right.

Comment: Which `$sql` do you want to run, the `update` or the `delete`?  The `delete` is the only one in the variable.

Comment: The error message tells you want is wrong. Look at your query -- how may `?` (parameter placeholders) are there? How many parameters are you passing to `bind_parm`?

Comment: Well, 3 != 2. Even if you copied the code somewhere, you should try to understand what it does. IHMO, it's clear that you just expect it to work.

Comment: *"Whats wrong with my php code?"* - That always starts off well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to remove the line with the `DELETE`, which is just overriding the first definition of `$sql`.

Then, you should replace the `$bool` with `?` in the `UPDATE`.

And finally, you should pass the parameters to bind_param in the same order as they appear in the query, so `$bool, $lat, $lng`.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement ends up being:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM markers WHERE lat=? AND lng=?";
```

Which only has 2 placeholders, and you're passing 4 values to bind_param().

Comment: oh i already deleted the Delete statement. still same error. :(

Answer (score 1):

replace this

```
  $stmt->bind_param("sss",$lat,$lng,$bool);
```

by

```
  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$lat,$lng);
```